# Как начать с новой строки при сцеплении двух слов в js?

Tags: javascript

Есть две переменных с текстом, которые мне нужно сцепить, чтобы получить одну строку.
Но сделать это нужно так, чтобы текст на который ссылается вторая переменная, начанался с новой строки. Как так сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поставьте между ними `\n` или `<br>`  - по обстоятельствам.